# Server Programming On Router(linux)

Tags: linux, facebook, api, share, router

Good Day.Our company have router with linux,having routing and everytime any device connects to router,it redirects to another page,and unless the user on its device wont hit the button,we wont let him to use internet.How am i able to make this work in a case that i want to make user 1st-share the link we give from router(without having access to internet from our router),2nd-if he had done sharing,give him internet access?I done couple researches but came across no nothing!
Example: http://hot-wifi.ru
This webpage having same what i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to force users to share something in order to get Wi-Fi access, as you can read in the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 4.5 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

That being said, you may want to take a look at this article about Facebook Wi-Fi: https://www.facebook.com/help/126760650808045/